# What is the practical purpose of "use raw as original" in Photos for OS X?

Tags: raw, photo-editing, jpeg, file-format, os-x

Within OS X Photos app, when I shoot jpeg/raw and upload to Photos, I get an image representing both files. By default I am looking at the jpeg. Or I can choose a command "Use Raw as Original".

I know conceptually that Raw contains more information and leaves the image processing to the computer not the camera. And I know conceptually that therefore I can possibly extract some more info out of the raw image file.

My question is as a practical matter, and specifically in Photos.app, what purpose is there to "Use Raw as Original"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is the *only* way to get the Photos application to work with the RAW file at all. If you use the edit features *without* doing this, you are working with the JPEG file instead of the RAW, with all that entails.